# PowerPoint print button does not prompt for print options

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I have a client computer who's Copy of Power Point 2007 goes straight to print when he presses the print button rather than asking him to select print options (essentially the print button works like the quick print button).  It doesn't happen on all documents but I've been unable to pin down a pattern of what documents do it and which don't.

Anyone have thoughts or suggestions on what to look at?  I've attempted to search Google but sadly just get multiple millions of hits on how to do normal printing, not fix broken printing.

Answer (score 1):

This is **normal** behavior in Microsoft Office 2010. To get to the printer options, you have to click **Printer Properties**. This [change](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954.aspx) is part of the new, streamlined **File** menu known as the [Backstage](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/what-and-where-is-backstage-view-HA010370584.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101887009).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Office 2007 not 2010.  Thanks for the input though.  Sorry I wasn't more specific up front.